# specify class within a class jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to toggle a hidden element within a list of posts when it is hovered. Similar to twitter, when you hover over a post, a menu of links will become unhidden.

Each row of posts has a class "post". Here is my current code:

```
$("div.post").mouseover(function() {
 $(this).css("background-color", "#f9f9f9");
});
$("div.post").mouseleave(function() {
 $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

Each row has a span class within it called "menu".

How do I go about toggling the span "menu" on and off for the hovered post?

Comment: This seems like a job for CSS, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple chain modification to original code:

```
$("div.post").mouseover(function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "#f9f9f9").find('span.menu').stop(true,true).slideUp();
}).mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).css("background-color", "white").find('span.menu').stop(true,true).slideDown();
});
```

Can change slide effect to `toggle()` for both and will hidde/show with no effect. The `stop()` will prevent jumpiness for quick in-out-in with mouse